# amazon s3 vs google cloud storage

Tags: amazon-s3, storage, google-cloud-storage

We are gathering information about different systems. At the moment we are looking for a storage solution. We will have a high amount of outgoing traffic with large files.

I want to compare s3 with google cloud storage.

google cloud storage costs around $0.08/GB at 90TB. S3 is around $0.06. But google cloud storage has already a cdn, which makes it way cheaper than amazon s3 with cloudfront.

Now I read somewhere that google cloud stroage is much slower than s3 with very large files. Is this true ?

I can not find any information.

What alternatives do I have if I have a high amount of outgoing traffic and large files ?

Edit:

benchmarks:

http://blog.zencoder.com/2012/07/23/first-look-at-google-compute-engine-for-video-transcoding/

Comment: We believe the zencoder analysis you cited encountered a bug causing their results to be negatively skewed. We think we understand the issue they encountered and are working to address it.

Comment: This might be interesting for you. Its from Ravelry who deals with many requests and images. To keep down costs they actually work with real hardware. http://codemonkey.ravelry.com/2011/05/16/saving-money-by-putting-a-web-cache-in-front-of-amazon-s3/

Comment: If you need high reliability and availability, Google may be more robust than Amazon. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud#Issues

Comment: I've found Google being quite unstable compared with AWS. e.g. the 'cloud console' has many issues, some of them laying there for almost a year, the keys/management console has some "lags"/get stuck sometimes, the billing/invoicing model is a total mess. Did I say that the google identity framework is a total mess too compared with AWS IAM? If you look for a price comparison Google may seem a cheaper but in terms of cloud services AWS is the leader! You should also check the other providers in town if the price / performance is your only comparison criteria.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about vendor pricing and product information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

2016 update - Look at this benchmark comparing AWS, Azure, and Google Cloud storage:

- http://blog.zachbjornson.com/2015/12/29/cloud-storage-performance.html

As a [reddit user commented](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/3zg3oc/aws_s3_vs_google_cloud_vs_azure_cloud_storage/):

> “Not for network throughput on GCP. It consistently beats out all of
>   the competition by a such huge margin that if you’re writing an App
>   that’s latency/bandwidth sensitive on the network side just ignore the
>   competition.”

---

For current pricing schemes, compare:

- https://developers.google.com/storage/pricing#pricing
- https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Performance is trickier to evaluate: You can get numbers, but those numbers will depend a lot on current conditions, network, proximity to datacenters, ratio of read/writes, etc.

Comment: Let's say you buy a hard drive. How much would a data center charge you to keep your hard drive online and replicated in different geographical zones throughout the month? Meaning: Are you comparing apples to apple seeds? Both have their uses, and are related to each other, but I'm sure apples are priced differently than seeds.

Comment: Exactly. I'm writing the comment for the thousands of readers on this page that are [about to pay the price of apples](http://blog.thecus.com/online-storage-costs-are-surprisingly-high-with-thecus-you-have-more-options/) when they are actually looking for apple seeds. You're likely **not** looking for apples and Yes, its possible to build a [top-50 website](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html) using apple seeds.

Comment: Now that's interesting, comparing the prices of a hard drive to S3 / Cloud Storage. You generally don't pay for the latter to store your personal photos of grandpa, if you just had to store that in the cloud, you can do that for free. You pay for S3 / Cloud Storage when you need to store files that will be accessed a lot, say for instance from a website or app. That's when you need 99.99% uptime, *really* fast internet, failure fallbacks, backups and all the other things you reliably can't set up at home for anyone near that price.

Comment: I know of no 'free storage' services > 10G range where I maintain ownership of the data that I can count on for archival purposes and not locked into another service.   Upload for 'free' to Facebook, Dropbox, G+ , Picassa , HP etc -- up to a few G yes.  Are they guaranteeing to keep my files and let me have them back and not share them? What is the SLA ?Only pure storage services like DropBox or Google Drive and only 'free' to a point.   If you want an SLA and ownership then it costs something.  Nothing is free.  Id rather pay $20/year/tb cloud storage for an SLA in writing and no strings.